# React useState hook (and useEffect) not working in callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Having tried useState, it's functiional variation and attempt with useEffect (not allowed in a callback function).

I am so stuck.
I have a parent 'Table' component, which renders a TableHead child and a TableBody child.
The TableHead child has a checkbox, which when clicked executes a callback function on the parent.
At this point the boolean selectAll (from a useState setter and value), is supposed to toggle (change value).
But it remains in it's initial state.
the result is that the first time the header checkbox for selectall, does fire and the re-render does show all the rows in the body as checked, but then unchecking the 'selectAll' does fire the callback, but the 'selectAll' remains false and all the rows remain checked.

Parent component Code:

```
function OTable(props) {

    const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState(false);

    const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
       if (selectAll === false)
       {
            setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = true);
       }
       else
       {
           setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = false);
       }
   }

   return (
    <TableContainer>
        <Table>
            <OTableHead
                onSelectAllClick={onAllRowsSelected}
                setSelectAll={setSelectAll}
            />
            <OTableBody
                selectAll={selectAll}
            />
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I make a couple of reasonable assumptions (for instance, that you have the closing `)` on the `useCallback` call), your code for toggling `selectAll` works, though from your use of `useCallback` I suspect it doesn't quite work the way you want it to. Here's your code with those assumptions:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

const TableContainer = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
const Table = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
const OTableHead = ({onSelectAllClick, children}) => {
    console.log(`OTableHead is rendering`);
    return <div>
        <input type="button" onClick={onSelectAllClick} value="Select All" />
        <div>{children}</div>
    </div>;
};
const OTableBody = ({selectAll}) => {
    return <div>selectAll = {String(selectAll)}</div>;
};

function OTable(props) {

    const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState(false);

    const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
        if (selectAll === false)
        {
            setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = true);
        }
        else
        {
           setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = false);
       }
    });

    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <OTableHead
                    onSelectAllClick={onAllRowsSelected}
                    setSelectAll={setSelectAll}
                />
                <OTableBody
                    selectAll={selectAll}
                />
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <OTable />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But some things stand out:

1. You're not passing any dependency array to `useCallback`. That doesn't do anything useful, because `useCallback` will always return the new function you pass it. I suspect you meant to have an empty dependency array on it so that it always reused the first function (to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of `OTableHead`).
2. You're using the callback form of `setSelectAll`, but you're using hardcoded values (`true` and `false`). This code:

   ```
   const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
       if (selectAll === false)
       {
            setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = true);
       }
       else
       {
           setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = false);
       }
   });
   ```

   does exactly what this code would do (given that we know that `selectAll` is a boolean to start with, it would be very subtly different if we didn't know that):

   ```
   const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
       setSelectAll(!selectAll);
   });
   ```

   because the `if` uses the version of `selectAll` that the function closes over, not the parameter the callback received. (`setSelectAll(selectAll => selectAll = false);` is functionally identical to `setSelectAll(() => false)`, assigning to the parameter doesn't have any effect.) And in turn, that code is the same as this:

   ```
   const onAllRowsSelected = () => {
       setSelectAll(!selectAll);
   };
   ```

   But I suspect you used the callback version for the same reason you used `useCallback`.

The code doesn't succeed in avoiding having the re-rendering, as you can see from the `console.log` I added to `OTableHead` above.

`useCallback` is useful for avoiding making child elements re-render if the callback hasn't really changed, by memoizing the callback. Here's how you'd use it correctly in that code

1. Pass an empty dependencies array to `useCallback` so it only ever returns the first callback you define.
2. Use the parameter value that the function version of `setSelectAll` passes your callback.
3. Ensure that the component you want to have not re-render if the callback didn't change implements checks on its properties and doesn't re-render when they haven't changed. With a function component like `OTableHead` you can do that just by passing it through `React.memo`.

Here's the example above with those changes:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

const TableContainer = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
const Table = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
// *** Use `React.memo`:
const OTableHead = React.memo(({onSelectAllClick, children}) => {
    console.log(`OTableHead is rendering`);
    return <div>
        <input type="button" onClick={onSelectAllClick} value="Select All" />
        <div>{children}</div>
    </div>;
});
const OTableBody = ({selectAll}) => {
    return <div>selectAll = {String(selectAll)}</div>;
};

function OTable(props) {

    const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState(false);

    const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
        // Callback version, using the parameter value
        setSelectAll(selectAll => !selectAll);
    }, []); // <=== Empty dependency array

    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <OTableHead
                    onSelectAllClick={onAllRowsSelected}
                    setSelectAll={setSelectAll}
                />
                <OTableBody
                    selectAll={selectAll}
                />
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <OTable />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you **aren't** worried about unnecessary re-rendering, then you can get rid of `useCallback` entirely and just do this:

```
const onAllRowsSelected = () => {
    setSelectAll(!selectAll);
};
```

Comment: If you don't add the dependency to the useCallback shouldn't return always the same value? Even if the dependency is not necessary because you don't use `selectAll` in `useCallback`. I'm confused...

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito - You're right, I mentally filled in an empty dependency array that isn't there. The OP's code, though eccentric, should work (though they probably didn't mean for the callback to change every time). I'll update or delete, thank you for flagging that up!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `useCalback` in this case. Just update setState like this:

```
const onAllRowsSelected = () => {
  setSelectAll((preState) => !preState);
};
```

Comment: `useCallback` memoizes the function so it doesn't constantly change, triggering re-rendering of the `OTableHead` component. So it's definitely useful to have it, they just need to do what you did in the body of the function: use the parameter the `setSelectAll` callback receives.

Comment: The main problem is about update state logic. He doesn't understand about `setState` so will should not talk about `useCallback`

Comment: I don't think that's the main problem, and without `useCallback` there's no need to use the callback version of `setSelectAll`. The OP's code would successfully toggle `selectAll`, though probably not the way they meant it to. I think the use of `useCallback` and the callback version of `setSelectAll` are important to the question, e.g., trying to avoid re-rendering of children like `OTableHead`.

Comment: For an experienced person, it's ok. But why do you think using `useCallback` is important with people who don't even understand `setState`?

Comment: I don't. My point is that I think the OP is using it for a reason. But they could just be confused. Again, though, there's no need for the callback form of `setSelectAll` in this case if you're not using `useCallback`. Anyway, hopefully the OP will come back and clarify. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keeps the inital value because `useCallback` is a memoization and, if you don't add the state dependencies, it keeps the initial value (due to the memoization itself). To solve, just put `selectAll` as `useCallback` dependencies:

```
const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(() => {
   setSelectAll((prev) => !prev)
}, [selectAll])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to memoize the state updater function since React guarantees it to be a stable reference.

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

You can simplify your callback to just update the state using the functional update.

```
const onAllRowsSelected = () => setSelectAll(all => !all);
```

If `OTableHead` requires that `onSelectAllClick` prop be a stable reference, then the `useCallback` can be used with an empty dependency array in order to provide a stable `onAllRowsSelected` callback reference. ***Note:** this doesn't effect the ability for `onAllRowsSelected` to correctly toggle from the previous state value, it's only to provide a stable callback reference to children components.*

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only
> changes if one of the dependencies has changed. ***This is useful when
> passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference
> equality to prevent unnecessary renders*** (e.g.
> shouldComponentUpdate).

```
const onAllRowsSelected = useCallback(
  () => setSelectAll(all => !all),
  [],
);
```

Comment: Ok, the `useState` part is clear. But if you don't add the dependency to the useCallback shouldn't return always the same value? Even if the dependency is not necessary because you don't use selectAll in useCallback. I missed something?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito That's sort of the idea with memoizing the callback, so it's always a reference to the same callback function instead of being redeclared each render cycle. If it's passed to children and it's a new reference then this possibly triggers unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: Ok, interesting, thanks,.. and if I want to query the value in the 'selectAll'? What if the setSelect All was not boolean, but say an integer (say  be able to toggle between 0 and 1  value,..would preState then need to be changed?

Comment: @NealRogers If you wanted to toggle between two values, use this pattern `setValue(value => value === <value1> ? <value2> : <value1>)`. The functional update is just a function, it takes the previous state value as an argument and only needs to return the next state value, you can apply any logic between these two points.